# ubuntu 12.04.3 - touchpad not working

Tags: installation, mouse, touchpad

I recently got an Acer laptop that had linpus Linux loaded on it, I found out that's not a very popular distribution so I am trying to install Ubuntu 12.04.3. I booted from flash drive and I get to the language selection screen but the mouse does nothing; however, the keyboard works fine and I can continue through the prompts with they keyboard.  I also tried a USB mouse and nothing.

Anybody have any idea why?  I am extremely new to Linux and am unsure of what to do.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I used to have this issue with Ubuntu 12.04.3 (64 bit). What I did was: Connect my USB mouse to the computer (it does not recognize it). Reboot the computer with both the mouse and the live USB device. Then restart. If it still doesn't work, go into the BIOS/UEFI then enable/disable/enable the internal touchpad. Then load Ubuntu on the USB drive. If it still doesn't work, tell me. Hope it helps (worked for me)

Comment: I tried that and no luck. I didn't see anything in the bios for the touchpad.  Should I try a different distribution?

Comment: Ok. First, can you give the exact (if possible), or approximate name of your device so that I can tell you about the bios. Meanwhile, have you thought about Debian, Fedora (which are great distributions; I use currently Windows 8 + Debian 7.1), or even the other Ubuntus (X-L-Kubuntu)? Thank you!